# simple number series

Tags: numbers, series

This is a simple number series question, I have numbers in series like 
`2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256` these numbers are formed by `2,2(square),2(cube)` and so on.

Now if I add `2+4+8 = 14`. `14` will get only by the addition 2,4 and 8.
so i have `14`in my hand now, By some logic i need to get the values which are helped to get `14`

Example:

```
2+4+8 = 14
14(some logic) = 2,4,8.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an easy one:

```
2+4+8=14 ... 14+2=16
2+4+8+16=30 ... 30+2=32
2+4+8+16+32=62 ... 62+2=64
```

So you just need to add 2 to your sum, then calculate ld (binary logarithm), and then subtract 1. This gives you the number of elements of your sequence you need to add up.

e.g. in PHP:

```
$target=14;
$count=log($target+2)/log(2)-1;
echo $count;
```

gives 3, so you have to add the first 3 elements of your sequence to get 14.

Comment: Eugen Rieck, can u please elaborate it,appreciate if you help me with the logic, and there is no digit 1 in my list

Comment: 1 was a typo, I just fixed it. I also added an example in PHP

Comment: Then you need to update your question to make clear, that you are searching for a solution to a totally different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following C# code:

```
x = 14; // In your case
indices = new List<int>();
for (var i = 31; i >= i; i--)
{
   var pow = Math.Pow(2, i);
   if x - pow >= 0)
   {
       indices.Add(pow);
       x -= pow;
   }
}

indices.Reverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use congruency module 2-powers: `14 mod 2 = 0`,  `14 mod 4 = 2`,  `14 mod 8 = 6`, `14 mod 16 = 14`, `14 mod 32 = 14`...
The differences of this sequence are the numbers you look for `2 - 0 = 2`, `6 - 2 = 4`, `14 - 6 = 8`, `14 - 14 = 0`, ...

It's called the p-adic representation and is formally a bit more difficult to explain, but I hope this gives you an idea for an algorithm.

Comment: hroptatyr,what if i choose 2+8+32 = 42, it fails.help me

Comment: 42 mod 2 = 0,
42 mod 4 = 2,
42 mod 8 = 2,
42 mod 16 = 10,
42 mod 32 = 10,
42 mod 64 = 42,
42 mod 128 = 42,
so it's 2 - 0 = 2, 10 - 2 = 8, 42 - 10 = 32, the rest is 0

Comment: @Rajneel: technically the sequence is endless but you can stop at the first power of 2 that is larger than your number (64 in case your number is 42).

Answer (score 0):

assuming C:

```
unsigned int a = 14;
while( a>>=1)
{
printf("%d ", a+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if this is programming, something like this would suffice:

```
int myval = 14;
int maxval = 256;
string elements = "";
for (int i = 1; i <= maxval; i*=2)
{
if ((myval & i) != 0)
elements += "," + i.ToString();
}
```