# Algorithm to produce number series

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am not sure how to attack this problem... I tried many things, and it seems to be that it shouldn't be so difficult, but not getting there...

Is it possible to create a function "series ( _x )", that produces this :

[image: example of wanted result]

The function for example should be myfunction( 11 ) => 211

Comment: _What_ have you tried so far?

Comment: Think of some number system very important to computer science. Count in that number system, then take another look at your problem.

Comment: Do you know the famous joke that starts like : "There are 10 kind of people in the world ... " ? The answer to it will lead you to the answer (if @z5h hint did not already).

Comment: Keep in mind this is not actually binary.

Comment: Just to add to my previous comment, as I believe people are giving incorrect advice. This list is in the form: (his series with 1 converted to 0, 2 to 1) -> (actual binary). `0 -> 0, 1 -> 1, 00 -> 10, 01 -> 11, 10 -> 100, 11 -> 101, 000 -> 110`

Comment: @andreee  I tried converting to binary, with indeed the abstraction that I doesn't really have to be 1 and 2, but could work with 0 and 1 as well. But that didn't work (straight out of the box). I also tried using square series as you can see that it approaches close to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291308/simple-number-series. The question with the latter is: how does iteration 13 knows that 14 is the closest one...

Comment: Count in trinary. Omit the values which have a zero in that representation.

Comment: @AndrewMorton if I would follow your approach, that would work, but it would mean I have to iterate, and even more then the number of iterations I actually need, as I have to omit certain ones. In term of performance this can get really slow I think.

Comment: @AndriesHeylen Computers are fast. *Really* fast. Try it.

Comment: Of interest: [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) query: [1,2,11,12,21,22,111,112](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C11%2C12%2C21%2C22%2C111%2C112&sort=&language=english&go=Search)

Comment: @GuyCoder The formula in that link you referenced actually matches the formula I came up with for my answer. Cool stuff :)

Answer (score 2):

This hint should help you... It isn't quite binary, but it is close. Let me know if you need any further help

```
   0    ->    -     ->    -
   1    ->    -     ->    -
  10    ->    0     ->    1
  11    ->    1     ->    2
 100    ->   00     ->   11
 101    ->   01     ->   12
 110    ->   10     ->   21
 111    ->   11     ->   22
1000    ->  000     ->  111
1001    ->  001     ->  112
1010    ->  010     ->  121
1011    ->  011     ->  122
1100    ->  100     ->  211
1101    ->  101     ->  212
1110    ->  110     ->  221
1111    ->  111     ->  222
```

Edit: I didn't like the way I ordered the columns, so I swapped 2 and 3

Python approach

First thing that we need to do is produce binary strings
in Python this can be done with `bin(number)`
However this will return a number in the form `0b101`
We can easily strip away the 0b from the beginning though by telling python that we dont want the first two characters, but we want all the rest of them. The code for that is: `bin(number)[2:]` left side of the : says start two spaces in, and since the right side is blank go to the end

Now we have the binary numbers, but we need to strip away the first number. Luckily we already know how to strip away leading characters so change that line to `bin(number)[3:]`.

All that is left to do now is add one to every position in the number. To do that lets make a new string and add each character from our other string to it after incrementing it by one.

```py
# we already had this
binary = bin(user_in + 1)[3:]

new = ""
for char in binary:
    # add to the string the character + 1
    new += str(int(char) + 1)
```

And we are done. That snippet will convert from decimal to whatever this system is. One thing you might notice is that this solution will be offset by one (2 will be 1, 3 will be 2) we can fix this by simply adding one to user input before we begin.

final code with some convenience (a while loop and print statement)

```py
while True:
    user_in = int(input("enter number: "))
    binary = bin(user_in + 1)[3:]
    new = ""
    for char in binary:
        new += str(int(char) + 1)

    print(user_in, "\t->\t", binary, "\t->\t", new)
```

Comment: I need to get my head around this, I don't even get on how to generate the number in the first column without iteration... I would like it to be non recursive, or with as less as possible iterations...

Comment: Ill add some more info to my answer for python :)

Comment: @AndriesHeylen Take a look at my python implementation and see if it helps you, Python does make trying things like this very convenient, but it could be done in other languages too (likely with a little more work)

Comment: yes but here it means I would have a dec to bin library at my disposal... which is not the case :)

Comment: @AndriesHeylen Many examples of these are available, check out [Geeks for geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-decimal-binary-conversion/) to implement one of those binary conversion methods. Your question however is not about binary conversion, and you have not indicated a programming language. If your original question (Is it possible to create a function that produces x)  has been solved by one of the answers provided please mark an answer as the correct solution and then approach your new problem from the start.

Comment: Another quick note is that all languages will store your numbers as binary (so regardless of how you choose to do the series, this step happens behind the scenes every time). They just choose to represent them with decimal when you interact with them. Most languages do have a way to get that binary value though. In java the method is Integer.toBinaryString(number), python uses bin(number), c# uses Convert.ToString(number, 2). Point is this functionality exists in most modern languages and since you did not indicate a language this functionality was assumed.

Answer (score 2):

The terms become suffix for the next terms. See below picture for more clarity. The boxes with same color gets repeated. So, we could just keep prepending `1` and `2` for previous results.

[image]

**Code(In java):**

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> ans = solve(10);
        for(int i=0;i<ans.size();++i) System.out.println(ans.get(i));
    }

    private static List<String> solve(int terms){
        List<String> ans = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] digits = new String[]{"1","2"};
        ans.add("1");
        if(terms == 1) return ans;
        ans.add("2");
        if(terms == 2) return ans;

        List<String> final_result = new ArrayList<>();
        final_result.addAll(ans);
        terms -= 2;//since 2 numbers are already added

        while(terms > 0){           
            List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            for(String s : digits){
                 for(int j=0;j<ans.size() && terms > 0;++j){
                     temp.add(s + ans.get(j));
                     terms--;
                 }
            }
            ans = temp;
            final_result.addAll(ans);
        }       

        return final_result;
    }
}
```

Comment: My current solution is O(n) where `n` is no. of terms. I did for generating the series anyway. You could do it for `myfunction( 11 ) => 211` in O(log(n)) time I presume with O(1) space.

Comment: might be I would use this algorithm, to first generate the whole list, as I would need all of them from 1..n, and then loop over the array to merge them... it might be faster...

Answer (score 1):

According to [A000055](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C3%2C6%2C11%2C23%2C47%2C106%2C235&language=english&go=Search)

We should perform `3` steps:

1. Convert `value + 1` to base `2`
2. Remove 1st `1`
3. Add `1` to the rest digits

For instance, for `11` we have

1. Converting `11 + 1 == 12` to binary: `1100`
2. Removing 1st `1`: `100`
3. Adding `1` to the rest digits: `211`

So `11` has `211` representation.

**C# code:**

```
private static String MyCode(int value) =>
  string.Concat(Convert
    .ToString(value + 1, 2)       // To Binary
    .Skip(1)                      // Skip (Remove) 1st 1
    .Select(c => (char)(c + 1))); // Add 1 to the rest digits
```

**Demo:**

```
var result = Enumerable
  .Range(1, 22)
  .Select(value => $"{MyCode(value),4} : {value,2}");

Console.Write(string.Join(Emvironment.NewLine, result));
```

**Outcome:**

```
   1 :  1
   2 :  2
  11 :  3
  12 :  4
  21 :  5
  22 :  6
 111 :  7
 112 :  8
 121 :  9
 122 : 10
 211 : 11
 212 : 12
 221 : 13
 222 : 14
1111 : 15
1112 : 16
1121 : 17
1122 : 18
1211 : 19
1212 : 20
1221 : 21
1222 : 22
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET, showing both the counting in base-3 and OEIS formula ways, with no attempts at optimisation:

```vb
Module Module1

    Function OEIS_A007931(n As Integer) As Integer
        ' From https://oeis.org/A007931

        Dim m = Math.Floor(Math.Log(n + 1) / Math.Log(2))
        Dim x = 0
        For j = 0 To m - 1
            Dim b = Math.Floor((n + 1 - 2 ^ m) / (2 ^ j))
            x += CInt((1 + b Mod 2) * 10 ^ j)
        Next

        Return x

    End Function

    Function ToBase3(n As Integer) As String
        Dim s = ""
        While n > 0
            s = (n Mod 3).ToString() & s
            n \= 3
        End While

        Return s

    End Function

    Function SkipZeros(n As Integer) As String
        Dim i = 0
        Dim num = 1
        Dim s = ""

        While i < n
            s = ToBase3(num)
            If s.IndexOf("0"c) = -1 Then
                i += 1
            End If

            num += 1

        End While

        Return s

    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("A007931  Base3   ITERATION")
        For i = 1 To 22
            Console.WriteLine(OEIS_A007931(i).ToString().PadLeft(7) & SkipZeros(i).PadLeft(7) & i.ToString().PadLeft(11))
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

```
A007931  Base3   ITERATION
      1      1          1
      2      2          2
     11     11          3
     12     12          4
     21     21          5
     22     22          6
    111    111          7
    112    112          8
    121    121          9
    122    122         10
    211    211         11
    212    212         12
    221    221         13
    222    222         14
   1111   1111         15
   1112   1112         16
   1121   1121         17
   1122   1122         18
   1211   1211         19
   1212   1212         20
   1221   1221         21
   1222   1222         22
```

Comment: this I think I understand, and I think I am going for the OEIS_A007931 function, as it is  easily extendible to other bases, and has the less iterations.

Comment: I implemented this one, and it works, but as I was afraid it is too slow, but I think this is more on how I do it. But thanks for this lead, I think I can play with this now!

Comment: @AndriesHeylen I would go with [Dmitry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56545796/1115360). If you need the function converted to VB: `Function MyCode(n As Integer) As String` `Return String.Concat(Convert.ToString(n + 1, 2).Skip(1).Select(Function(c) (Integer.Parse(c) + 1).ToString()))` `End Function`.